# Js Jquery td auto numbering with custom locale language

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Is there any way to auto numbering table data with local or custom language. I'm a Bengali, I know how to auto numbering table each row 1st data using css and js. But I don’t know how to use custom number, e.g. Bangla or Arabic.

Look at my code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want something like that;

১. Apple
২. Banana
৩. Orange
৪. Strawberry

How can I get that using Javascript / jquery.. Without adding any third party plugin.

Comment: You need to build the library by yourself then if you don't want to use another library. You may check the topic i18n

Comment: Thats Mean You're saying that, I need additional library or 3rd party for that ?

Comment: Yes, to have the data of the numbers over languages..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `toLocaleString()` method or `Intl.NumberFormat()` constructor with the locale language as a parameter.

For example.

1. For Arabic numbers `num.toLocaleString('ar-EG')`.
2. For Bangla numbers `num.toLocaleString('bn-BD')`

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');

[...table.rows].forEach((row, index) => {
  row.cells[0].textContent = (index + 1).toLocaleString('bn-BD')
})
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Jazakallah Khairan Mina.... Thanks A Lot..

Answer (score 1):

A CSS only solution would be using the CSS `counter(..)` function and pass the *counter-style* parameter (`list-style-type`) for 'bengali'.

E.g. `td::before { content: counter(some-counter, bengali) }`

Reference: [MDN: counter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) and [MDN: list-style-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type)

```css
table {
    counter-reset: row 0;
}

tr {
    counter-increment: row;
}
td::before {
    content: counter(row, bengali) '. ';
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>red</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>black</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```